# On what basis is the load switch input and output capacitance recommended in datasheet?

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, decoupling-capacitor

**I am seeing different output cap recommendations for 2 load switches with similar specs.** What is the basis for this calculation?

[SLG5NTH1011V](https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/sites/default/files/slg5nth1011r100_04052017.pdf)

[image]

[SLG59H1017V](https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/sites/default/files/slg59h1017r103_10172019.pdf)

[image]

Comment: EEVBlog has a whole video where he plugs in different capacitors and looks at the output, pretty entertaining if you're into that sort of thing (like me). As for low ESR, well, high ESR means you have effectively a resistor before the capacitor, which, if significant, defeats the whole purpose of the capacitor to charge/discharge quickly

Answer (score 1):

Those are manufacturer suggestions, and for two completely different parts with two completely different operating specifications.

The manufacturers have calculated, designed and tested various scenarios for the different parts that when the given rated capacitances are used, the parts work well within the specifications they are rated for.

There may be no such detailed info how these values are suggested. The values are given with specific minimum and maximum limits, so there is no single correct value, and they also try to optimize the value as smaller capacitance may be cheaper etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Silego device has a MOSFET switch that has an on-resistance of typically 50 mΩ whereas the Dialog part has an on-resistance of typically 5.1 mΩ. The operating maximum currents are also different; Silego is 3 amps whereas Dialog is 5 amps.

There is also the operating frequency of the internal charge pump to consider but, we can't make comparisons because neither data sheet provides details.

You are not comparing apples with apples.

To make this even worse, your Dialog data sheet extract is for the SLG59H1017V device but your link is to the SLG59M1717V. In engineering, precision is required (and common sense).

Comment: The SLG59M1717V's datasheet linked in the OP suggests that the output capacitor can be anything between 1 to 600 uF :)

Comment: @RohatKılıç precisely!!!

Comment: oops! corrected the link

Comment: @DivyaK.S given that you appear to have fixed the link, my answer still generally stands in that you are making comparisons between two different devices (from different suppliers) with different specs yet you are expecting some equality. That just won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Low ESR e-caps in this value range have an ESR * C = T time constant between 1 and 20 us and is constant in the same family.

General purpose e-caps are > 10 x worse for ESR and are generally not listed, rather instead D.F. %.

So the bigger the cap. C value,mfor the same volume, voltage and chemistry

1. the more energy storage available but also
2. the bigger the ESR and also
3. the lower the SRF (self resonant frequency) .

This in turn can affect closed loop stability, surge current, power limits and ripple voltage.

So choice of low ESR e-cap will depend on one or more of those 3 variables and many consequences.

- but as always  \$Ic = C*dV/dt +\Delta V/ESR\$ for a step load with the switch resistance and cap. ESR limiting current for ESR.